# Can we copy of all incoming and outgoing emails in exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, email-server

I have installed a exchange 2007 in my home

I have 3 users on this server

1. user1
2. user2
3. user3

user 1 is user where I want to monitor all the email activity of users 2 & user3

what I want is to receive all the incoming and outgoing email copies in user1...

is this possible in exchange server 2007.

or any other way to monitor the incoming and out going emails in exchange 2007?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is in the Transport Rules. You can specify Transport Rules such that all mail coming in gets copied to specific users. Transport Rules are specified in the Hub Transport role. There is a nice wizard for setting up Transport Rules which will guide you through conditions and actions.